# Is being able to drive a prerequisite to system administration and network administration job?

Tags: software-industry, nepal

I'm based in Nepal. Is it mandatory to have vehicle license for every kinds of this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really really depends on the organisation.

It may not be mandatory by the law of the land, but the organisation may add a specific requirement and you have to abide by that. If the job posting says it needs to have certain license / clearance / skills, then there is a very good chance they'll insist on having them.

In case the job involves managing multiple different systems located in same city but not in the same building / premises, then there is a possibility that they'd prefer someone who can drive down to the site having the issue, without the need of waiting for someone to drive them around, or needing the organisation to arrange for a transportation every time.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @sourav's answer, some sysadmin (and other jobs, like doctors) require residency within, say,an hour's drive or 50 miles of a location so you can quickly arrive if "on call."

All depends on the details/role of the job though. The interviews are the time to ask these questions in order to get a better understanding of the role and requirements.

Comment: Being able to drive will not be a prerequisite in an area where taxis are available at any time. The company will prefer not to pay for taxis.